# @XmlRootElement not working in jersey rest

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey

ERROR:

> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class com.example.DemoRest2.Employee, genericType=class com.example.DemoRest2.Employee.

I want to return the object of  Employee.class in xml format but getting above error.
I am using @XmlRootElement annotation. However, it works fine when I return it in string format.

EmployeeRsource.java

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("employee")
public class EmployeeResource {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Employee getEmp() {
    
    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setName("Tom");
    e1.setAge(25);
    System.out.println(e1);
    
    return e1;
}
}
```

Employee.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Employee {

private String name;
private int age;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
}   

}
```

Getting "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500" on user interface

I am already having following dependencies:
jersey-media-jaxb - 3.0.2
jaxb-api - 2.3.1
jersey-container-servlet-core
jersey-hk2
jersey version - 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The Jakarta EE Working Group has announced that javax is now officially and finally renamed as jakarta with the release of the Jakarta EE 9 Platform and Web Profile specifications and related TCKs.

To use that @XmlRootElement ,
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement,
after adding following ,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.33</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue all you need to do is instead of returning an object return a string. Using an XmlMapper, which is a subclass of ObjectMapper, create a string and return it. However, the object which will be converted into a string needs to have the same configs as the employee object in the case above.
How to do it.

step 1: Get the required dependency for the XmlMapper class.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

step 2: Inside the method that you intend to return xmls with create an XmlMapper object.

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
```

step 3: Now convert the object that you intend to return as an xml into a string using the xmlMapper object created above. In the example provided above, the object to return was employee hence el has been used here.

```
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(el);
```

Step 4: return the string

```
return xml;
```

NB: your method or controller will have to return a String and not an Employee object in this case. Additionally, use `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` above your resource to signal to your consumer what to expect.

Also, in your consumers' header, it is good but not necessary to show what you are expecting from the server by using a `Accept: Application/xml` in your headers. It is not necessary since most consumers by default accept all data formats.